# Update golang software, but keep installed go apps/packages

Tags: go, updating

I am on Linux (debian) and want to update a global go installation. (not installed from debian repo, but manual install into /usr/local)

The installation/update instructions on [go.dev/doc/install](https://go.dev/doc/install) state:

> Remove any previous Go installation by deleting the /usr/local/go folder [...] then extract the archive [...] into /usr/local, creating a fresh Go tree in /usr/local/go

But I installed some go apps using `go install` (e.g. go-sendxmpp), which reside now in /usr/local/go/bin, /usr/local/go/pkg

Therefore my question: How can I update the Go software without also deleting all my installed go apps?
What am I missing here?

Comment: In the future you should not be installing any other binaries into GOROOT/bin.

Answer (score 4):

Move the executables to a different directory.  Update your environment variables to install to a different directory.

`go install` installs executables to the directory named by the GOBIN environment variable, which defaults to $GOPATH/bin or $HOME/go/bin if the GOPATH environment variable is not set.

If `go install` installed go-sendxmpp to /usr/local/go/bin, then you set GOBIN to /usr/local/go/bin or GOPATH to /usr/local/go. Set these environment variables to point somewhere else.  It's typical to point them a personal directory or not set them at all.